# freeStyleJob SCM credential from parameters not working

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I'm trying to use a simple [FreeStyleJob SCM](https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#path/freeStyleJob-scm-git) , and set the credentialId UUID from build parameter. The problem is, it seems the credentials is not parsing the parameter correctly.

```
scm {
    git {
        remote {
            github('\${MY_REPO_HANDLE}', 'ssh')
            credentials('\${MY_REPO_CREDENTIALS}')
        }
        branch('\${MY_BRANCH}')
    }
}
```

My MY_REPO_CREDENTIALS is a simple String parameter

```
stringParam {
        name("MY_REPO_CREDENTIALS")
        defaultValue("teste-credential")
    }
```

Log:

```
Warning: CredentialId "${MY_REPO_CREDENTIALS}" could not be found.
```

**UPDATE**

This Jenkins Job is created by another Jenkins Job using DSL external. In resume, Job 1 whenn triggered will create the Job 2 on jenkins. When I try to use **"$ (without \)** the job will fail because this parameter doesn't exist on Job 1 context.

job config.xml:

```
<scm class="hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM">
<userRemoteConfigs>
<hudson.plugins.git.UserRemoteConfig>
<url>git@github.com:${MY_REPO_HANDLE}.git</url>
<credentialsId>${MY_REPO_CREDENTIALS}</credentialsId>
</hudson.plugins.git.UserRemoteConfig>
</userRemoteConfigs>
<branches>
<hudson.plugins.git.BranchSpec>
<name>${MY_BRANCH}</name>
</hudson.plugins.git.BranchSpec>
</branches>
<configVersion>2</configVersion>
<doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations>false</doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations>
<gitTool>Default</gitTool>
<browser class="hudson.plugins.git.browser.GithubWeb">
<url>https://github.com/${MY_REPO_HANDLE}/</url>
</browser>
</scm>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final solution was set the ssh agent before build, using wrapper:

```
wrappers {
        sshAgent("\${MY_REPO_CREDENTIALS}")
    }
    keepDependencies(false)
    scm {
        git {
            remote {
                github("\${MY_REPO_HANDLE}", 'ssh')
            }
            branch("\${MY_BRANCH}")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can switch to using `"` instead of `'` so you can use the autofill feature:

```
scm {
    git {
        remote {
            github("${MY_REPO_HANDLE}", 'ssh')
            credentials("${MY_REPO_CREDENTIALS}")
        }
        branch("${MY_BRANCH}")
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Cirrith ! Thanks for your help :) I think it's important to say, this jenkins job is created by another jenkins job. Job 1 will use DSL external to add this Job 2. Job 2 is the one we are talking about. When I use your suggestion Jenkins fail because this parameters doesn't exists in Job 1 context. Using  "\${MY_REPO_CREDENTIALS}" for example, jenkins job will succeed but the parameter cast will only worked for MY_REPO_HANDLE and MY_BRANCH.